# PHP variable with string

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get an image using the following

```
$html ='<a href="#"><img alt="" src="'.bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/my-image.png"></a>';
```

When I return `$html` the path from `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')` shows in the top portion of the page instead in the src attribute of the image.

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing a quote in `<a href="#>` - Look at your HTML source.

Comment: fixed but get same issue

Comment: That's why it's a "sidenote" ;)

Comment: Does the `bloginfo()` method `echo` or `return` the path?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo: _“This always __prints a result to the browser__. If you need the values for use in PHP, use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo).”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead. And you are missing a quote (as CyberJunkie pointed out). Try this:

```
$img_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/my-image.png';
$html = '<a href="#"><img alt="" src="' . $img_path . '" /></a>';
```

There is also a sample in the wordpress codex:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/aternus.png" alt="" title="" width="" height="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) will automatically echo out the directory you are requesting, and has no return value.  The output happens *when you are building your string*, not whenever you are `echo`ing the `$html` variable.

I think the function you are looking for is [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Example usage of `bloginfo` (notice no `echo`):

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

Example usage of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```